# Get everything before and after a certain character

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

Get everything before and after a certain character in SQL

I want the second string after '_'.

Example:

```
A_1234_BCD_8977_90888
```

Output:

```
1234
```

SQL Server 2016

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, SQL Server has a whole bunch of string functions which will allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN col LIKE '%_%_%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(col,
                        CHARINDEX('_', col) + 1,
                        CHARINDEX('_', col, CHARINDEX('_', col) + 1) -
                            CHARINDEX('_', col) - 1)
         ELSE 'NA' END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The idea is to take a substring between the first and second underscores.  `CHARINDEX` lets us find those two positions, then we need to do a bit of number crunching to find out the length of substring to take.

Comment: How to check if it contains _ or not. Otherwise it will give  "Invalid length paramater passed "

Comment: @Cherry Follow Dale's advice, and see the updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes JSON helps. You may try to transform the input text into a valid JSON array (`A_1234_BCD_8977_90888` into `["A","1234","BCD","8977","90888"]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`. With this apporach you can get each part from the input text by position:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @position int = 2
DECLARE @text varchar(1000) = 'A_1234_BCD_8977_90888'

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@text, '_', '","'), '"]'))
WHERE CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 = @position
```

Result:

```
1234
```

Note, that `STRING_SPLIT()` is not an option here, because the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.